# jira: git notes support in git plugin for jira?

Tags: git, jira, jira-plugin

I am using git as my SCM and jira as the defect tracking tool. I have a requirement wherein i want to add jira url in the notes section of the git. With jira being a licensed software, is it ok to create a custom plugin which can handle git notes?

Comment: what notes section of git?

Comment: i meant 'git notes'???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: nothing in the "[JIRA Plugin Guide](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Plugin+Guide)" prevents you to do so, and the "[Recently Updated Add-ons for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/app/jira)" has its share of free plugins.

Currently though, [processing JIRA issues is done with commit messages](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Processing+JIRA+issues+with+commit+messages), not with [`git notes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes). Those are called [smart commits](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Processing+JIRA+issues+with+commit+messages), used through the "[JIRA DVCS Connector](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-bitbucket-connector-plugin)".